# How to divide data across time?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, sql-types

Actually, I've faced this issue working with T-SQL but the its a logical and mathematical problem at all, so I've decided to try my luck here.

What I have is a some data in the following format:

```
Date                 Score
2012-11-01 12:11:50  12
2012-11-02 15:20:20  42   
...
2012-11-15 20:32:21  21
```

So, we have accurate date and some score with each record. Next, a user enters a number (1,2,3,...) which says on how many equal time periods to dived the all records and sum the score in them.

So, what I was doing now, was (let's say the user wants 3 periods) to:

1. Get the first and the last records' date and calculate the days
   difference between them
2. Divide the results (let's say we have 30 days) on number of the
   periods in order to get how many days I have in each period.
3. Calculate the periods first date of each period like **first date + ( number of days in period * period sequence number)**
4. Check in which period is the date and sum the score there

That was working at first, but then I met a lot of issues, and here I should said that its very important to use **days** as period measurement, but if not possible to make a solution using days, we can use hours or minutes to minimize the errors.

And here are the issues:

1. If I have one record and more than one period my solution is not
   working, because in **step 2** we have (for example the user wants 3
   periods) 1/3=0 (because we are working with days and
   1/3=~0.333days=0 (in the context of T-SQL and BIGINT variable). So,
   in **step 3** the calculation of the first date of each period will
   give us three same first dates.
2. If I have smaller days in interval (for example the first date is
   2012-12-01 and the last date is 2012-12-03 the difference is three
   days) then desired periods I will met the same issue again, as in
   T-SQL 5/6 for example is 0 again.
3. If I have 10 periods, but 11 days, then one of the periods will be
   with one days bigger.

So, the task is to divided the records in equal time periods and sum the score in each period. I see how bad is my solution (using the days)  but I am open and will welcome each idea and proposal.

Comment: You are aware that this StackExchange site is about the software program [MathematicA](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) and not about MathematicS? There is a separate site for that: math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Since the issues are to do with numeric types in T-SQL I feel that this question should either be on StackOverflow or DBA.SE. It is marginal for mathematics.SE (probably will not be accepted) and definitely inappropriate here. Voting to close as OT.